# Use variables like #1 in math

Tags: macros, variable

I'm writing this small `\newcommand`, and I want to send numbers as parameters. But since the math mode always tries to interpret the `#` in a different way. I don't know what to do. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
\newcommand{\scoring}[1]{%
\begin{center}
    $K^1=$#1      % this does work, however it looks ugly
    $K^1=#1$      % does work
    $K^1=\#1$     % does not work
    $K^1=\{#1}$   % does also not work
\end{center}
}
```

I call this command with this:

```
\scoring{4}
```

So a 4 should appear.

Comment: Off-topic: Why you have to use `\begin{center} $a=b$ \end{center}` when you already have `\[a=b\]`?

Comment: I don't find any problem with simple command definitions like `\newcommand{\scoring}[1]{$K^1=#1$}` or `\newcommand{\scoring}[1]{\[K^1=#1\]}`.

Comment: `$K^1=#1$` should actually work in that it would output K^1=4. Can you show us a complete example document where that goes wrong, please? I agree with JouleV that `\begin{center}$...$\end{center}` looks suspiciously like you want `\[...\]` or `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` or `align`....

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\scoring}[1]{\[K^1=#1\]}
\begin{document}
\scoring{4}
\end{document}` works flawlessly for me

Comment: Further checking: the first line works; the second line also works; the third line doesn't work because it is not `#1` anymore -- it is `\# 1`; the fourth line doesn't work because of syntax error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem cannot be replicated.

Comment: You guys are right, after a reboot the second option worked.

Comment: @JouleV you are right the first ones work. But the first one looks ugly.

Comment: @PhilRoggenbuck Of course the first ones work. But the more complicatedly you do, the more ugly you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\newcommand{\scoring}[1]{%
  \begin{center}%
      $K^1=#1$\\%     
      $K^1=\{#1\}$\\%
      $K^1=\string###1$\\%
      $K^1=\{\string###1\}$\\%
      $K^1=\{\##1\}$\\%
      $K^1=\{\sharp#1\}$%
  \end{center}%
}

\begin{document}

\verb|\scoring{4}|:

\scoring{4}

\verb|\scoring{5}|:

\scoring{5}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Better use `\#` (or maybe `\sharp`) instead of `\string##`.